# Absolute position element causing scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I have created an auto complete drop down box that adds an abosultely positioned table at the end of the input box when user enters some data in an input box. But the problem is I have scroll bar appearing on the right

[image]

I want to make it look something like this where there is no scrollbar by changing the position of the table to relative. But as you can see it increases the height of the outer table and adding z-index to relatively positioned element does not do anything apparently. I think sticking with absolute position is better because I don't think there is a way to expand the drop-down box without expanding the table using relative positioning.

[image]

My HTML is setup like this:

```
<div class="autocomplete">
   <input name="partNumber[]" class="partNumberInput parts form-control fireChange" type="text" aria-describedby="enter Part Number" placeholder="Part Number" >
    <table id="autocomplete-list" class="autocomplete-items table table-dark  table-bordered table-sm dropDownTable">
   <thead>
       ....
```

The table is absolutely positioned whereas the 2 outer divs are relatively positioned.

Comment: I am guessing but doesn't the overflow property suppress scroll bars with the right values?

Comment: I can add `overflow:hidden` but then the drop down never appears

Comment: can you post more codes please, that would be helpful

Comment: can you try creating a sample demo .